# How can I put the empty subfloat subcaptions to the right?

Tags: positioning, captions, subfloats

I'm putting two figures above each other with `\subfloat` from the `subfig` package. Their captions are empty as I just want to describe the figures with the main caption, but I still want the `(a)` and `(b)` subcaptions to show up, so that I've got something to refer to.

How can I put those tiny subcaptions to the right of the subfloats instead? They're eating my precious vertical space.

Here is a minimal working (but not as I'd like to) example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics{pic-1.png}%
        \label{label-1}%
    }\\%
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics{pic-2.png}%
        \label{label-2}%
    }%
    \caption{This is the text that describes \subref{label-1} and \subref{label-2}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

I started looking at the `subcaption` package, but it claims to be incompatible with `subfig`.

Comment: Would you be able to include a full compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @Werner: Sure, I've added one now.

Comment: I am interested in seeing a solution to this problem, but are you sure you want to do this? In languages that read from left-to-right, having the caption on the right hand side of the figure might be distracting.

Comment: @cmhughes: The actual pictures are plots with the Y-axis to the left, and I don't want too much text in different fonts close to each other. I was browsing through a textbook using this technique though, so I suppose it isn't horrible. Thanks for your comment, I hadn't thought of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `\sidesubfloat` command provided by the `floatrow` package (this, however, will put the subcaptions to the left of the subfloats):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure}
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{pic-1.png}\label{fig:sub1}}\\[10pt]%
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{pic-2.png}\label{fig:sub2}}%
  \caption{Two subfigurfes with their caption beside}\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Note that `\centering` is in effect by default with `floatrow`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer as that's what I ended up doing, even though Werner answered the actual question :)

Comment: @TimN: Well, that's a bummer. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow sub-figures
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics{pic-1.png}}\ \subfloat[\label{label-1}]{} \\[\topskip]
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics{pic-2.png}}\ \subfloat[\label{label-2}]{}
  \caption{This is the text that describes \protect\subref{label-1} and \protect\subref{label-2}.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The above example typesets the image (dropped by a half its height) and then inserts an empty `\subfloat` for captioning/referencing purposes.

Comment: Thank you! What does `[\topskip]` do?

Comment: While `\\` causes a line break, adding an optional `<len>` (that is, using `\\[<len>]` you can specify the line break gap. So, I specified a vertical gap of `\topskip` for the line break. See the difference when using something like `\\[\baselineskip]` or `\\[40pt]`, for example.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise `\\` was a command, much less that it had an argument. Another new thing I've learnt today!