# How to put caption beside?

Tags: captions, subfloats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caption on the side of a figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure)

Can anyone tell me how to get my caption of subfloats on their right side? Here is my example.

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=10cm]{Figure1.jpg}}\\
\subfloat[]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=10cm]{Figure2.jpg}}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you complete your code to a compilable one such that we can see if other details will interefere?

Comment: I think that [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38518) might be what you're looking for.  There are some other options [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29143/14100)