# How to place the sub label of a figure to the right using package `subcaption'

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, chemstyle

I am creating a scheme and I need to add to figures, but I want the figures to have the sub caption to the right, this because my figures could be also seen as equations. I don't know if a minimal working example would be useful, but I am including one:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont={bf},margin=1em,labelsep=period,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[!h]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \schemeref[TMP1]{1}
    \CNlabelnoref{1}
    \schemeref[TMP2]{2}
    \CNlabelnoref{2}
    \schemeref[TMP3]{3}
    \CNlabelnoref{3}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Subfig1}
    \caption{}
    \label{subsch:Subscheme1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \schemeref[TMP4]{4}
    \CNlabelnoref{4}
    \schemeref[TMP5]{5}
    \CNlabelnoref{5
    \schemeref[TMP6]{6}
    \CNlabelnoref{6}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Subfig2}
    \caption{}
    \label{subsch:Subscheme2}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Scheme1}
\label{sch:Scheme1}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Here is the link for Subfig1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbb5134l99ftk08/Subfig1.eps
Here is the link for Subfig2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gr582dqc4zww9vu/Subfig2.eps

Someone made a question just like this one ([How can I put the empty subfloat subcaptions to the right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38518/how-can-i-put-the-empty-subfloat-subcaptions-to-the-right?rq=1)) , but they were using `subfig` package, I want to know if that can be done using the package `subcaption`

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Going straight and simple. Use `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelfont={bf},margin=1em,labelsep=period,textformat=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering 
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}   
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%                <--- you need this %
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \caption{}
    \label{subsch:Subscheme1}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{subfigure}%                 <--- you need this %
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering    
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}%               <--- you need this %
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \caption{}
    \label{subsch:Subscheme2}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Scheme1}
\label{sch:Scheme1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]